# Signal Message Chat Bot

Tags: бот, signal

Возможно ли создать бота для сигнала который би читал сообщения вместо пользователя, реагировал на заданные триггеры/слова/фразы и пересылал эти сообщения в чат человеку? Может у кого есть примеры или может помочь с написанием такого?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, можно создать бота для чтения и реагирования на сообщения но сложно. Вот пример кода на Python для такого бота:

> бот - пользователю: Здравствуйте! Я бот, который может читать
> сообщения в чате и реагировать на определенные слова и фразы.
>
> Чтобы я начал работать, мне нужно определить список ключевых слов, на
> которые я буду реагировать.

Например:

```
triggers = ["привет", "как дела", "пока"]
```

Затем нужно ввести в цикл для вечного отслеживания новых слов в чате:

```
while True:
new_message = get_new_message()

for trigger in triggers:
if trigger in new_message:
# реагируем на сообщение
respond_to_message(new_message)
```

Функция `respond_to_message(message)` будет содержать логику форmирования ответных сообщений.

Таким образом, бот сможет автоматически читать входящие сообщения и реагировать на ключевые слова, имитируя поведение человека. Естественно, функционал можно расширять - добавлять обработку естественного языка, интеграцию с внешними сервисами и т.д.

Comment: Что такое `get_new_message`?

Comment: Функция get_new_message() в приведенном примере отвечает за получение новых сообщений из чата.

Она может быть реализована по-разному, в зависимости от того, с каким чатом или мессенджером вы работаете.

Для чат-ботов в Telegram, ВКонтакте и др. это будет вызов API
Для чатов на сайтах - обращение к WebSocket или поллинг REST API чата
Для CLI чатов - чтение данных из stdin потока
и тд.

Comment: То есть текст вопроса вы даже не читали? Вы написали уже четыре ответа с чушью, может хватит?

Comment: текст я прочитал. пример код я брал с опыта прошлых работ и примеров с интернета, но я не могу привести более точного примера и работы ведь такой тип работы очень сложный и я просто не знаю где что и как вы хотите сделать.